# pass a javascript via ajax and process with php

Tags: php, javascript

I need to pass a javascript object , info is a javascript object.

```
register.php?t="+accessToken+"&u="+info
```

in php i tried to change

```
$data = $_GET['u'] ;

var_dump($data);
```

It's not working help me to slove,

Comment: Did you got any output of your `var_dump` ? Try to `var_dump($_GET)` and write, what you get.

Comment: Can you post an example of contents of the info var?

Comment: What is "accessToken"? Can we see some of the AJAX code?

Comment: Can you verify that it does create the correct URL?

Comment: The ever popular incredibly accurate "it doesn't work" symptom.

Comment: accessToken another string variable

Comment: There's not enough detail in this question for anyone to be able to help you. Please tell us what is stored in `accessToken` and `info`, i.e. provide examples of the data. When you've done that flag to re-open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should encode your javascript object into json format, so you can pass it into the uri. Here is how to do that: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php

and then on the server side you can simply do:

```
$data = json_decode($_GET['u']);
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the object's complexity, you might want to serialize it first and pass it to your script.

Example ([Prototype JS](http://www.prototypejs.org)):

```
var obj = {some: "data", yet: "more"};
new Ajax.Request('register.php', {
    // object is serialized here
    parameters: {u: Object.toJSON(obj)},
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Then in register.php, unserialize accordingly:

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST['u']);
var_dump($obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify or serialize the object.

If you are using jQuery it would be easy, just search for jQuery serialize.

Otherwise there are plenty of functions that will serialize the object for you.

http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+serialize